# iOS Binding Library doesn't work on simulator, but it works on device

Tags: ios, storyboard, xamarin, wrapper, flyout

I’m trying to create wrapper for controller: https://github.com/ipup/PPRevealSideViewController.

Using these instructions http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_walkthrough/ I have created iOS Binding Project. Since this controller doesn’t created for working with Storyboard, I’ve modified it (that is replace initialization to other method, in order to Objective Sharpie doesn’t wrap it to constructor).

To test how controller works I have created project as in original controller (PPtest) example, which haven’t use Storyboard and controller has initialized from code. This project works both simulator and device.

Project with Storyboard (StoryboardPPTest) works fine on device, but it crashes during slider drag & drop without throwing any exception.

Could you suggest what the problem is?

I have attached sources with original controller, makefile to create Fat Library, iOS Binding Project, and 2 test projects: PPTest and StoryboardPPTest, and .crash file.

Attachment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lb798o5fddkclze/Flyout%20Problem%20Attachment.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Xamarin.iOS.

I've found a workaround however:

- Add `--registrar:dynamic` to the additional mtouch arguments in the project's iOS Build options.

This will give you the same behaviour in the simulator as on device.